# Normalising a database table

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

I'm looking for some advice on how to normalise my 'Property' table below. I believe it is currently in the first normal form, and everything apart from CountryID,RegionID and DistrictID depends on the primary key PropertyID.

- [PK]PropertyID
- [FK]CountryID
- [FK]RegionID
- [FK]DistrictID
- [FK]SettlementID
- [FK]FacilitiesComboID
- [AT]NoOfRooms
- [AT]PropertyType
- [FK]ReviewsID
- [AT]PropertyName
- [AT]Longitude
- [AT]Latitude
- [FK]AddressID

Is the table below the property table in 2nd normal form? Any advice is greatly appreciated

- [PK]PropertyID
- [FK]FacilitiesComboID
- [AT]NoOfRooms
- [AT]PropertyType
- [FK]ReviewsID
- [AT]PropertyName
- [AT]Longitude
- [AT]Latitude
- [FK]AddressID

Comment: Reviews wouldn't be a part of this table.

Comment: Ok, so the propertyid would be the foreign key in the reviews table? Is my table in the 2nd normal form other than that?

Comment: I'm suspicious about the ComboID - but it could be a valid way of doing things. Essentially, I'd say yeah, this looks pretty good. There's a subtle redundancy in terms of storing both coords and address, but that's fine.